# Filter mongoose query results against current user provided by Passport.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I have Passport.js set up with JWT authentication.

I would like to automatically or manually filter mongoose query results based on the user object provided by Passport.

```
Word.find(req.query, function (err, words) {
  if (err) {
    res.json({
      message: err
    })
  }
  res.json({
    data: words
  })
})
```

Here, `req.query` would be used to filter results based on the query, but the access would be given to only specific documents related to the user present given by `req.user`.

How is it possible to achieve that in the best manner?

Comment: your `req.query` needs to contain a reference to `req.user` so that only information for that target user is returned. If you dont do this, and validate the user is who you intend, you are basically setting yourself up for sql injection

Comment: Right, so I should override the user field in `req.query` with req.user before executing the request?
req.query.created_by = req.user._id
then
Word.find(req.query, ...)

Comment: yup, but again, if you dont pass some sort of auth token, then you cant be sure if someone else is polling your API, but spoofing their req.user value. Be careful here.

Comment: That should be fine if I override that value before querying right? req.user is insured by JWT.

Comment: yea, absolutely. if JWT is used, then you should be solid (so long as you are using `verify()`.